# Select all records where column B only has distinct instances of column A

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I don't know how to explain this situation, it's a bit tricky so I'll try to give you an example of the data I have and the output I need:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable( A int, B int)
INSERT INTO #TempTable (A,B)
VALUES 
(1,1),
(1,2),
(1,2),
(1,4),
(3,2),
(3,2),
(3,2),
(3,3),
(3,3);
```

I can't figure out how to select all records such that the final output is:

```
1,1
1,4
3,3
3,3
```

<strike>I need the records where column B only has distinct instances of column A. All other instances should be ignored...</strike> I feel like this should be pretty simple, but I'm blanking out and I can't figure it out.

**Update:**

I've been having a hard time explaining this, but I think this is the correct logic: you can have duplicate instances of B for a given A, but you can't have duplicate instances of B across different A's.

Comment: I must be missing something why is 3,3 in your list given the rules you defined...

Comment: What database system do you use?

Comment: @xQbert You can have duplicate instances of B for a given A, but you can't have duplicate instances of B across different A's.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek MS SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT A, B FROM TempTable
WHERE B IN (
  SELECT B
  FROM TempTable
  GROUP BY B
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT A) = 1
)
```

Working example on MS SQL 2012: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d235a/4

Comment: Missing the 3,3's; I think my requirement needs to be revised: you can have duplicate instances of B for a given A, but you can't have duplicate instances of B across different A's.

Comment: I've been having a hard time trying to actually describe the requirement, because it's a bit obscure, but I think I've finally narrowed it down.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
with cte as
(select t.*, min(A) over (partition by B) minA, max(A) over (partition by B) maxA
 from #TempTable t)
select A, B
from cte
where minA=maxA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A, B, COUNT(A) as NumPairs 
FROM TempTable 
GROUP BY A, B 
HAVING COUNT(A)=1
```

SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ee6c5/9

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.A, t1.B
  FROM TempTable t1
  LEFT JOIN TempTable t2
    ON t1.B=t2.B AND t1.A<>t2.A
WHERE t2.A IS NULL;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d235a/5